# Remove external Docker container registry dependencies / only store container images on Amazon ECR

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, amazon-ecr

So I am using Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR) to store our containers.  I have a container that is built using a Microsoft base image:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
```

What I am finding is that when I then push my container image to Amazon ECR, and then later I pull this image - it is STILL downloading the base layer from mcr.microsoft.com!

I am using Docker for Windows Server (not Docker for Linux).

I don't want this because mcr.microsoft.com is super slow and unreliable.  Plus Microsoft keeps breaking the links by changing the names of the servers.

How do I get docker to NOT store an "external link" for the first layer to mcr.microsoft.com and instead store everything on Amazon ECR?

Answer (score 1):

If you push an image to ECR you are no longer relying on the "first layer" of your dockerfile for the image you built. If you have a Dockerfile that has a `FROM` that points to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2016` and you build an image off of this Dockerfile, you can push to ECR and you are no longer dependent on the `mcr`.

I am wondering if you are somehow still pulling from `mcr` in your `docker pull` syntax?

Your pull should have have a syntax along the lines of `docker pull aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my_image:my_tag` and such a command won't depend on `mcr`

Comment: Hmm this is what I thought but somehow it is still pulling the first layer from mcr and not amazon ecr.  I am using the FROM command as you say above - is it possible that is somehow the reason?  Is there a parameter in FROM to prevent this?

Comment: Also please note this is Windows Server 2016 and not Linux

Comment: The only way to pull from `mcr` would be at `docker build` time. Once you have built the container and pushed to ECR you are basically only pulling from ECR. How/where do you see it's still pulling from `mcr` when you pull from `ECR`? What does it make you say " it is still pulling the first layer from mcr and not amazon ecr"?